# Complex if statement in bash

Tags: bash

How to I write the following statement without getting `Conditional binary operator expected` Error?

```
if  [[ test "${EXPRESSION}"  || ( ( ! -f file1 )  && ( ! -f file2 ) && ( ! -f file3 ) ) ]]; then
doSomething
```

Comment: Remove `test`. What is the content of `EXPRESSION`?

Comment: Your `test` command does not make much sense. Perhaps you meant `test $EXPRESSION`? If you want to compute the arguments for `test` dynamically, I would make `EXPRESSION` and array and do a `test "${EXPRESSION[@]}"` instead, to avoid problems with arguments containing white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash

Testing that `$EXPRESSION` is not empty:

```sh
[[ $EXPRESSION ]]
```

Testing that there's no  file `file1`, no file `file2` and no file `file3`:

```sh
! [[ -f file1 ]] && ! [[ -f file2 ]] && ! [[ -f file3 ]]
```

whose logic could be expressed with: *there's not any file `file1`, `file2` or `file3`*:

```sh
! [[ -f file1 || -f file2 || -f file3 ]]
```

So to sum it up:

```sh
if [[ $EXPRESSION ]] || ! [[ -f file1 || -f file2 || -f file3 ]]
then
    domSomething
fi
```

Comment: thank you, the part placing the exclamation mark before the brackets was the missing link.

Comment: You also where using parenthesis, which are subshells. `-f` doesn't have any special meaning anything in it

Comment: @Lokomotywa you should accept the answer (the check mark on the left of the answer) if this solved your question.